# The way to pull out html section tags nested inside inline tags

Tags: python, html, lxml

Our application gets *html* content from customer and process it using python's module `lxml`. We don't have possibility to edit the content before it comes to our app.

Some of the strings in the input content have the following problem: *html* section tags (e.g. `<center>` or `<p>`) appear inside inline tags (e.g. `<b>`). For instance:

```
s = '<b><p>foo</p></b>'
```

By default `lxml.html.HTMLParser` fixes it by just extracting wrong inline tags:

```
html.tostring(html.fromstring(s))
```

yields

```
<div><b></b><p>foo</p></div>
```

It affects the way the output *html* code looks in a browser (the word `foo` is not in bold any more).

**Is there a more or less generic way to pull out *html* *section* tags from *inline* tags?**

Following the same example, we want to obtain this string:

```
<p><b>foo</b></p>
```

The naive solution would be just swap the appropriate tags, but it does not work for the string like that:

```
<b><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></b>
```

We would appreciate any solution: concrete libraries or just algorithms.

Comment: s/section tags/block tags/

Comment: You could use BeautifulSoup _with the `html.parser` parser_ to avoid the "auto fix" feature of the `lxml.html.HTMLParser`, and then reorganise the DOM "by hand" - but beware this will not be a funny task.  Or you could just reject invalid html markup and tell your customers to fix it themselves <g> (yeah I know, that's most often not an option...)

Comment: It would be great to have the algorithm which  reorganizes the DOM. And yes, you are right: unfortunately, the second way is not an option.

Comment: Well, both of your above cases can be solved easily with BeautifulSoup (once you understand the dom manipulation features), but a robust generic solution is another beast really so I'm afraid you'll have to do it by yourself. If it was easy I would gladly have posted a working solution...